# Confused about FCM and Push plugin in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

I have to develop an `app` with **push notification** in `ionic` where on notification click user should redirect to a specific page.

I searched and found two **plugins**`(FCM and Push)`, But I am confused about their differences, How do both work? Which is the best to implement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is already there on [ionic forum:](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/fcm-or-push/101413/2)

Here's the accepted answer there:

> If you are using Firebase, use the FCM/Firebase one. If you use any
>   other push provider (like Ionic Push or OneSignak), use the other one.

And for me I'll go for FCM, it being easier to implement.

Comment: Sir @BlackMamba, can you tell me FCM notification will work if I run my app in the browser or not? Do I need to handle browser notification?

Comment: No they won't work on browser. They can only be tested on device. Haven't tried on simulator I think they won't run on simulator as well you'll have to run on real device only.

Comment: So for the browser how can I implement? because I have requirement where the ionic app will run on a browser, android, and ios,

Comment: https://medium.com/@david.dalbusco/add-web-push-notifications-to-your-ionic-pwa-358f6ec53c6f